# Text moving because of javascript text updates, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, shake

I'm working on some exercises on my own. And I've created this simple page that is updated by this function

```
function today(){    
    hoje = Date();  

    switch (hoje.slice(0,3)) {
        case 'Mon' :
            todayIs = 'Monday';
        break;

        case 'Tue' :
            todayIs = 'Tuesday';
        break;

        case 'Wed' :
            todayIs = 'Wednesday';
        break;

        case 'Thu' :
            todayIs = 'Thursday';
        break;

        case 'Fri' :
            todayIs = 'Friday';
        break;

        case 'Sat' :
            todayIs = 'Saturday';
        break;

        case 'Sun' :
            todayIs = 'Sunday';
        break
    }

    todayInFunction = new Date;
    hours = todayInFunction.getHours();
    if (hours < 10 && hours < 12){
        hours = `0${hours} AM`;
    } else{
        hours = hours + 'PM';
    }
    minutes = todayInFunction.getMinutes();
    minutes < 10 ? minutes = '0' + minutes : false; 
    
    seconds = todayInFunction.getSeconds();
    seconds < 10 ? seconds = '0' + seconds : false;
    
    console.log(`Current time is: ${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`);
    
    printHere = document.getElementById("print-here");
    printHere.innerHTML = `Today is ${todayIs} <br> Current time is: ${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
}

    setInterval(
        () => {
            today()
        }, 1000
    )
```

And the problem is that the text shakes every second because of the text content being updated. Is there any CSS trick that I could use to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide us your current HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this. Being center aligned, the text will be centred in relation to how much its width is. If your text is centred and is constantly changing it will shift.
My suggestion is having the second line in it's own element with display: block, giving it a max-width, aligning the text to the left and centring that element using magin: 0 auto. You will also have to fiddle with the first lines margin bottom to for it to look the same way. or you could just nest the second line into the first one.
It may be kind of hacky but it will likely do the job. It should look something like this.

HTML

```
<p>Today is Tuesday</p>
<span class="time">Current time is: OO AM: 11: 17</span>
```

CSS

```
.time{
   display: block;
   max-width: X;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
 }

p{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Note that I'm going in blind and I don't know how you structured your code. I'm solely basing this on the image you sent.